# why the character's head hidden?

Tags: html, css

I have created the scrolling bar, but I find is good:

```
<a href=http://www.blueidea.com/updatelist.asp target=_blank class="f12red"><h2>iii</h2></a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sstong123/ZKKFU/29/

I defined .myfont css doesn't work good, it lost head, like iii displayed as 111, how to define the css?

```
<a href=http://www.blueidea.com/updatelist.asp target=_blank class="f12red"><font class="myfont">iii</font></a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sstong123/ZKKFU/32/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in your `myfont.css`.You defined `padding-bottom:3px` so it hides the letters.reduce that will work good

```
.myfont {
    font-size: 18pt;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Check this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ZKKFU/33/

Answer (score 0):

I viewed your code. iii doesn't display as 111. Its actually iii, but the dot of "i" is not visible because of the bottom padding. Try removing `padding-bottom: 3px;` from .myfont of your css and it would work fine.